# How do I add an image above the title in an article class org-mode pdf export?

Tags: image, pdf, emacs, latex, org-mode

I wish to add a small image above the title when I export to pdf from org-mode

I am using the 'article' class currently.

I have attempted to use:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \includegraphics{logo.png}
```

But this only places the graphic on the first page on its own. The rest of the document starts on the second page.

Is there a way to either add an image in an absolute position in a document or add one at a certain point and center it within org-mode? If not, is this possible from within a custom org-export-latex-classes class?

Comment: I would try to hack '\maketitle' and solve your issue directly in TeX. Implement your solution as a small LaTeX package and include it in your org file.

Comment: I've resorted to using \includegraphics in the title for now and adding a newline. Creating a custom latex package seems to be the only way to go really in the long term.

Comment: Maybe the following answer of mine (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22960107/671013) could be helpful