# configure org-mode to use one package if compile with beamer another else (article)

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I want to use one package if I compile with beamer or another one if I compile with pdflatex (org-latex-pdf-process):

```
if compile-with-beamer:
  \usepackage{my_beamer_package}
else:
  \usepackage{my_article_package}
```

NB:

```
C-c C-e l P     (org-beamer-export-to-pdf)
    Export as LaTeX and then process to PDF.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible starting point: use the LaTeX macro [`\@ifclassloaded`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97/412). More precisely, in your `org` file use a local package

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{myPackage}
```

and in this package have the following code:

```
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}
  {\usepackage{my_beamer_package}}
  {\usepackage{my_article_package}}%
```

Comment: actually I import package in init file of emacs like this: `(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "myPackage"))`. And next I tr tried what you write in package. But if I compile as beamer (`C-c C-e l P`) or as latex (`C-c C-e l p`) it never goes in the else case. But I also tried by importing in my org file.

Comment: Thank you,thoughtlessness in my pavkage.

Comment: I found it more straightforward to include the `MyPackage` directly from the `.org` file as I described in my answer.